# socket question: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am writing a simple socket app, and I have met this message and don't know how to fix it.

```
server_input =s.recv(1024)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

server.py

```
import socket
def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    port = 58257
    client_address = "localhost"
    s.bind((client_address, port)) 
    s.listen(2)
    user_input = input("Enter a message: ")
    s.send(user_input.encode())

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client.py

```
import socket


def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    #host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 58257
    client_address = "localhost"
    s.connect((client_address, port))

    print("connet ")
    server_input =s.recv(1024)
    server_input.decode()
    print("Received message: " + server_input)

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It is there any problem with my code? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
s.bind((client_address, port)) 
s.listen(2)
user_input = input("Enter a message: ")
s.send(user_input.encode())
```

The server needs to call `accept` on the server socket to get a socket for the connected client, then call `send` on this connected socket, not on the server socket.

Without this the `connect` in the client will still succeed, since it is done by the OS kernel on the server side. But since the connected socket is never `accept`ed by the server it will be reset, thus resulting in the error you see.

So a more correct code on the server side would be

```
...
s.listen(2)

c,_ = s.accept()
user_input = input("Enter a message: ")
c.send(user_input.encode())

c.close()
```

Note that your client code has also other problems, i.e it should be

```
print("Received message: " + server_input.decode())
```