# While trying to receive in Server socket: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

first of all, I tried the solution here

[socket question: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74698506/socket-question-connectionreseterror-errno-54-connection-reset-by-peer)

but it was irrelevant because I have `socket.accept()`
and I am receiving the message (I printed the received message).
I'm trying create a login or signup server.
I wanted the server to send the options, (sign-up or login).
after I receive the answer from the client, I get:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

the server code:

```
#server

import socket
import threading
import userNode

HEADER = 64
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5062
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
# HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def get_user():
    pass

def send_options(conn):
    options = ["Connect", "Create Account"]
    full_message = ""
    for i in range(len(options)):
        full_message+=f"{i+1}."
        full_message+=f"{options[i]}\n"
    send(msg=full_message,conn=conn)

def receive(conn):
    msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_length:
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
    return msg

def send(msg, conn):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER-len(send_length))
    conn.send(send_length)
    conn.send(message)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        send_options(conn=conn)
        msg = receive(conn=conn)
        if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            connected = False
        print(f"[{addr}]: {msg}")
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {HOST}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIOS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

client code:

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5062
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    # encoding the message
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    # getting the length of the message
    msg_length = len(message)
    #encoding the msg length to send to the server
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    #padding the message to 64
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    #sending the header and the message itself
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)

def receive():
    msg_length = client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_length:
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = client.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
    return msg

print(receive())
msg = input()
send(msg)
```